# "Хоть вам и рады простодушно" - что значит?

Tags: лексика

Добрый день!
Я француженка, часто читаю по-русски или смотрю по телевидение, но иногда не понимаю некоторых выражений.
Я очень рада познакомиться с вами.
Сегодня хотела бы понять, что Пушкин в писме Татяны в "Онегине" пишет:
... ничем мы не блестим,
**"Хоть вам и рады простодушно"**
Спасибо за ранее,
Женти-коклико

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте, женти-коклико!

Попробую объяснить.

(Вам) Рады = Мы счастливы =  Nous sommes très heureux.
Простодушно = бесхитростно = ingénument. Но здесь это значит "искренне" = sincèrement.
Так что всё вместе, наверное, будет "Nous sommes sincèrement heureux de vous**.

Простите, уровень моих познаний французского не позволяет быть уверенным в качестве перевода, но смысл, надеюсь, понятен. И ещё. Это язык Пушкина, и высокий стиль. Сейчас так не говорят, поэтому могут быть трудности в понимании. Мой совет, посмотрите хороший перевод "Онегина" на французский.

Comment: спасибо вам. Теперь всё ясно. ваш француз замечательный